# How to create separated sections in one report?

Tags: sectioning, numbering

Here is my codes

```
  \documentclass[a4paper,15pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{titling}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{ {images/} }

    \usepackage[top=30pt,bottom=40pt,left=100pt,right=100pt]{geometry}
    \begin{document}
   %=============================First article
    \title{AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA}
    \author{GH}
    \maketitle

    \section{introduction1}
    \section{result1}
    \section{conclusion1}


    %============================= The following is the second article



    \title{BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB}
    \author{Se}
    \maketitle

    \section{introduction2}
    \section{result2}
    \section{conclusion2}

    \end{document}
```

I want to put in two articles in one document file, so the two article should have different introduction section. What I want is that:

```
title 1
1, introduction
2, result
3, conclusion

title 2

1, introduction
2, result
3, conclusion
```

But what I get from my codes is that the section number is continuous. How to fix that?

```
title 1
1, introduction
2, result
3, conclusion

title 2

4, introduction
5, result
6, conclusion
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\setcounter{section}{0}` should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert my comment into an answer: You can control the counting of sectioning commands using counters. For you the section counter is important, so you can reset with `\setcounter{section}{0}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,15pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\usepackage[top=30pt,bottom=40pt,left=100pt,right=100pt]{geometry}
\begin{document}
%=============================First article
\title{AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA}
\author{GH}
\maketitle

\section{introduction1}
\section{result1}
\section{conclusion1}


%============================= The following is the second article
\title{BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB}
\author{Se}
\maketitle
\setcounter{section}{0}

\section{introduction2}
\section{result2}
\section{conclusion2}

\end{document}
```